# Polymorphism via Interface

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have one interface

```
public interface AA {
    public void sayHello();
}
```

and implement it from one class

```
public class B implements AA {

    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello !");
    }
}
```

and a class has one method with parameter type of above interface

```
public class C {
    public void invoke(AA aa) {
        System.out.println("Invoking !");
    }
}
```

construct them in my main class as

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        c.invoke(b);
    }
}
```

output at my console `Invoking !`.

I don't understand **Polymorphism** very well in case. Why `invoke(AA aa)` method of class **C** can accept instances of class `B`? Are all class the same by implementing the same `interface`?

**For an example:**

I have **Student.java** and **Teacher.java** classes. If they `implement` one interface with a single method `gotoSchool()`. They can pass any methods with parameter type of an interface that these two classes implemented? If so, can I assume instances of **Student** class and **Teacher** class are the same?

Please somebody help me what's wrong with my thinking? I only know that **polymorphism** happens when you `extend` same class. But I don't know about implementing an `interfaces`.

Comment: Because B is also AA. Between B and AA, there is an IS-A relationship  - B IS-A AA.

Comment: Interface is a general contract which all the implementer class should satisfy. If a class satisfies the contract, you can treat the object from the class in the same way that you use the object of the interface. (you cannot see the difference.)

Comment: @bjlee72 I think I should assume they are the sames because just only sharing their behaviors (methods).

Comment: Right. You can treat them in the same way, because support the same set of operations in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why invoke(AA aa) method of class C can accept instance of class B ?

Because class `B` also implemented interface `AA`

> Does all class are the same by implementing a same interface ?

Yes. It's like having an interface `Animal`. When your class `Dog` implements `Animal` `Dog` now **IS-A(n)** `Animal`. If `Cat` implements `Animal`, `Cat` now **IS-A(n)** `Animal` also.

> I just only know about polymorphism to extends same class. But I don't know using with Interfaces.

Polymorphism is not just limited to extending a class. It also happens when you implement an interface.

In your given example with `Student` and `Teacher` class. Let's say you have an interface called `SchoolGoer` and your `Student` and `Teacher` implements it, now you can say that every instances of `Student` and `Teacher` **IS-A** `SchoolGoer`

You can now do something like this:

```
SchoolGoer aTeacher = new Teacher();
SchoolGoer aStudent = new Student();
aTeacher.goToSchool();
aStudent.goToSchool();
```

Since they both implemented the `SchoolGoer` interface, they can both do whatever a `SchoolGoer` does. In this case `goToSchool`.

Answer (score 1):

It is the beauty of Inheritance. It's not polymorphysm. Simply we can define polymorphysm is "Same thing in multiple ways".  Your program `AA` is a interface. `B` is a sub Class, inherite from `AA` interface. Therefore we can say

> `B` is `AA`

In your `C` class `invoke(AA aa)` method accepting any `AA` type thing. So `B` is `AA`. Therefore that method accepting `B` class object. You can't give `AA` instance(Because we can't create objects using interfaces). As well as you can use `Annonymous class` for running that method. It is like this..

```
class Main {
public static void main(String... args) {
    //B b = new B(); 
    C c = new C();
    c.invoke(new AA(){
      public void sayHello(){
      System.out.println("Annonymous class");
      }
    });

 }
}
```